# JUnit tests in Eclipse Indigo reporting nothing?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

I'm trying to get JUnit 4 tests to properly run in Eclipse Indigo SR1, but something is screwy. In the simplest case that I can think of (as below):

```
package ints;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class IntTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setUp()");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("assertEquals(1, 1);");
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("assertEquals(1, 2);");
        assertEquals(1, 2);
    }
}
```

When I run this in Eclipse (Alt+Shift+X, T), the JUnit view reports "Runs: 0/0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0" while the console displays the below, but I'm not getting anything else. I can throw exceptions from the test methods & they aren't displayed either.

```
setUp()
assertEquals(1, 1);
setUp()
assertEquals(1, 2);
```

Any ideas as to what gives?

Comment: Hm, strange. Just for fun I opened a new workspace & tried it. Still nothing.

Comment: Java 1.7.0, 32-bit & 64-bit. Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried with Java 1.6.x?

Comment: I tried Java 1.6. First uninstalled all my JDKs/JREs. Then installed 1.6u29 (32 & 64 bit) & it worked. Installed 1.7u1 (64 bit) & it worked. Installed 1.7u1 (32 bit) & it stopped working. Uninstalled 1.7u1 (32 bit) & it started working again. I have it working which is nice, but this feels like magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason uninstalling the 1.7 32-bit JDK solved this problem for me. It didn't seem to be on the path or anything that I could figure out. It feels a little too much like magic, but it worked.

I had 4 JDKs installed (1.6 & 1.7, 32-bit & 64-bit). Now I have 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have both JUnit 3 and JUnit4 installed on your system and the project imports the wrong version of JUnit. This will cause all sorts of weird problems.

In your case it seems the code isnt being treated as tests at all, which makes sense if you are using JUnit3.

Check your buildpath to see which JUnit you are using.

Comment: Unless Eclipse is lying to me, org.junit_4.8.2_v20110321-1705\junit.jar is sitting on the classpath (via Plug-in Dependencies or directly via JUnit4).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you noticed this, but my System.outs are being written out so my code is being called.

Comment: Hmm. Yea, you are right. Well, the code is right, so the fault must lie elsewhere. You sure the JUnit view is displaying your test? It should say something like "IntTest [Runner: JUnit4] (0.0000s)". Same result if you right click on the project and choose "Run as..." - "JUnit test"?

Comment: The JUnit view displays "IntTest" and then switches to "Terminated". The console displays the above output. I get the same result (minus the displayed name) if I right click on the project & run as a JUnit test.

Comment: And it also says "[Runner: JUnit4]" ? If so, then I'm all out of ideas. Try downloading a new Eclipse and try the old workspace. Start a new workspace/project and try the old eclipse installation. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: It doesn't say "[Runner: JUnit4]" anywhere. The console displays "IntTest [JUnit]" as the program title. I've tried a new Eclipse with old & new workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with JUnit. I ran update on my good old JDK, but the problem remained, so I completely deleted all JDK-s from my machine and installed the newest jdk 6 and the Eclipse Indigo magically started to work properly.

Maybe the continuously updated jdk 6 is not correctly upgraded...

Answer (score 0):

Check the (local) firewall rules on the machine. I bumped into the same issue one year ago and allowing local connections for Eclipse/Java solved the issue. (I've just found a note about this.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. JUnit start but not working and not finished and not give any exception. For me worked check firewall iptables command and add run:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

JUnit need this permission to running - allow internal interface communication.